# Get output logs from windows query modem

Tags: winapi

How can I catch this output logs by using Delphi ?

[image: windows query modem]

On picture is my cellphone, but it could be any other modem. I need to get the result form "Query Modem"

I want my program be able to make query such modem and get the output logs.

update question:
I want to see that kind of logs (not exactly same) by using any possible way. It is okay if need to dealing with com port component. My concern is the result from `ATI1`

Comment: Maybe from the text file specified by "the pattern" in [this topic](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771018(v=ws.10).aspx)?

Comment: yes Victoria. But i want my program have own button for "Query Modem" and i will capture the logs. Sorry, my question was unclear. I just aware the location for the logs. Thank you so much.

Comment: The way windows receives this information is by sending special AT commands to the modem. It is possible to do the same from your application but you will probably need some third party component. Since I haven't been fiddling with this for over 10 years now I can't do any more specific recommendation. Another thing that you might want to check is Windows TAPI (Telephony API) which is the software interface that Windows uses for communicating with old phone based modems.

Comment: @SilverWarior Thanks, i am installing com component. This is new things for me. Wanted an example :)

Comment: Restricting your question with the Delphi tag hardly helps. Far more chance of help if you'd just used a single tag, winapi.

Comment: Thank you sir, i updated my tags.

Answer (score 4):

You can connect to the modem via your com port.

Use something like Turbo Power's Async Professional (free, open source).

http://tpapro.sourceforge.net/ApdComPort.html

Send the AT commands that you need, and catch everything that the modem returns.

Comment: This has nothing to do with logs that are saved by modems in the system..

Comment: @Victoria it is pretty obvious from the screenshot that the log in question is being generated by sending specially crafted AT commands to the modem.

Comment: @Remy, maybe it's not related at all. This question doesn't say that the OP is sending those commands.

Comment: I concern than my button will render such output, doesn't matter how the way it is. I was thinking if there any windows console application that do the job, but i did not found it.I never do com at-commands things before, maybe need to start to learn it. Any example would be appreciate.

i see one close vote, i hope tomorrow this thread still open, so i can start bounty.

Comment: @Bianca, that close vote is not mine but I understood your question as that it's not you who's sending those commands. I thought that you just want to see logs of devices having their own drivers. Could you clarify this in your question, please?

Comment: Close vote is mine @Bianca, the reason being "too broad". You should either start [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363140(v=vs.85).aspx) (or for a more focused article see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff802693.aspx)), or as this answer suggests learn to use some 3rd party library.

Comment: @Victoria I want to see that kind of logs (not exactly same) by using any possible way. It is okay if need to dealing with com port component. My concern is the result from `ATI1`. Anyway, bounty started. I hope someone with generous heart will spend time for me :)

@SertacAkyuz Im just starting to learn, sir.